# how to perform a runtime view update when using ResourceViewLocationProvider

Tags: c#, razor, static-methods, nancy

I`m runing a nancyfx with owin on centos 6.5 with mono 5.10.0.140, I change the default ViewLocationProvider to ResourceViewLocationProvider for the default ViewLocationProvider causes memory leak of somekind after running for days, and the ResourceViewLocationProvider don`t have the same problem. I would like to hot update Views just like what we can do with a default ViewLocationProvider, but it seems impossibe when googling around.

I did find a partial solution though, by implenting a custom IViewLocator and a IViewCache, I did achieve someking of hot update. But It didn`t feel right aside from those ugly static class

```
//Here is what I did in the custom IViewLocator
//...class definition fallback viewlocator and other staffs
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, ViewLocationResult> _cachedViewLocationResults;
//..other code      
    public ViewLocationResult LocateView(string viewName, NancyContext context)
    {
//...lock and others
        if (_cachedViewLocationResults != null && _cachedViewLocationResults.ContainsKey(viewName))
        {
             return _cachedViewLocationResults[viewName];
        }
//...lock and others
       return fallbackViewLocator.LocateView(viewName, context);
   }
//...other class
//here is how I update Views
public static void UpdateCachedView(IDictionary<string, ViewLocationResult> replacements)
{    
    lock (CacheLock)
    {
        if(_cachedViewLocationResults == null)_cachedViewLocationResults = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ViewLocationResult>();
        foreach (var replace in replacements)
        {
           _cachedViewLocationResults.AddOrUpdate(replace.Key, x=>replacements[x], (x,y)=>y);
        }
   }
}
```

//END OF IViewLocator

```
//here is what I did in the custom IViewCache
//another static for ViewCache to tell if the view has been updated
public static List<ViewLocationResult> Exceptions { get; private set; }
//...some other code
//here is how I ignore the old cache
public TCompiledView GetOrAdd<TCompiledView>(ViewLocationResult viewLocationResult, Func<ViewLocationResult, TCompiledView> valueFactory)
{
    if (Exceptions.Any(x=>x.Name == viewLocationResult.Name && x.Location == viewLocationResult.Location && x.Extension == viewLocationResult.Extension))
    {
        object old;
        this.cache.TryRemove(viewLocationResult, out old);
        Exceptions.Remove(viewLocationResult);
    }            
    return (TCompiledView)this.cache.GetOrAdd(viewLocationResult, x => valueFactory(x));
}
```

With those implentions and a little bit of settings on the bootstrapper plus a router for some mysql update, I can update the View the way I want, but here is the problem:
1. now I have to manually map all the Location,Name,Extension for the ViewLocationResult to use and there are too many of them (243...), I would like to use the some sort of built-in function to identify the changes, something like the IsStale function of the ViewLocationResult, but I didn`t know which and how...
2. those static class are ugly and I think it could be problematic but I didn`t know a better way to replace them.

Could some one kindly give me a hint, thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally figure out how to do this myself, just in case anyone else want to use the same method as I do, Here is how you update your view in memory:

1. Make a interface

```
    public interface INewViewLocationResultProvider
    {
        bool UseCachedView { get; set; }
        ViewLocationResult GetNewerVersion(string viewName, NancyContext context);
        void UpdateCachedView(IDictionary<string, ViewLocationResult> replacements);
    }
```

2. Make a new ViewLocationResultProvider

```
public class ConcurrentNewViewLocationResultProvider : INewViewLocationResultProvider
    {
        private Dictionary<string, ViewLocationResult> _cachedViewLocationResults;
        private readonly object _cacheLock = new object();
        public bool UseCachedView { get; set; }

        public ConcurrentNewViewLocationResultProvider()
        {
            lock (_cacheLock)
            {
                if(_cachedViewLocationResults == null)_cachedViewLocationResults = new Dictionary<string, ViewLocationResult>();
            }
        }

        public ViewLocationResult GetNewerVersion(string viewName, NancyContext context)
        {
            if (UseCachedView)
            {
                if (Monitor.TryEnter(_cacheLock, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20)))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (_cachedViewLocationResults != null && _cachedViewLocationResults.ContainsKey(viewName))
                        {
                            return _cachedViewLocationResults[viewName];
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Monitor.Exit(_cacheLock);
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        public void UpdateCachedView(IDictionary<string, ViewLocationResult> replacements)
        {
            lock (_cacheLock)
            {
                if(_cachedViewLocationResults == null)_cachedViewLocationResults = new Dictionary<string, ViewLocationResult>();
                foreach (var replace in replacements)
                {
                    if (_cachedViewLocationResults.ContainsKey(replace.Key))
                    {
                        _cachedViewLocationResults[replace.Key] = replace.Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _cachedViewLocationResults.Add(replace.Key,replace.Value);
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

3. In your Bootstrapper,register the new ViewLocationResultProvider with tinyIoc or equivalent

```
container.Register<INewViewLocationResultProvider, ConcurrentNewViewLocationResultProvider>().AsSingleton();
```

4. Make a derived class from ViewLocationResult

```
    public class OneTimeUsedViewLocationResult : ViewLocationResult
    {
        private bool _used = false;
        public OneTimeUsedViewLocationResult(string location, string name, string extension, Func<TextReader> contents)
            : base(location, name, extension, contents)
        {
        }

        public override bool IsStale()
        {
            if (_used) return false;
            _used = true;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

5. And a new IViewLocator:

```
public class CachedViewLocator : IViewLocator
    {
        private readonly INewViewLocationResultProvider _newVersion;
        private readonly DefaultViewLocator _fallbackViewLocator;
        public CachedViewLocator(IViewLocationProvider viewLocationProvider, IEnumerable<IViewEngine> viewEngines, INewViewLocationResultProvider newVersion)
        {
            _fallbackViewLocator = new DefaultViewLocator(viewLocationProvider, viewEngines);
            _newVersion = newVersion;
        }

        public ViewLocationResult LocateView(string viewName, NancyContext context)
        {
            if (_newVersion.UseCachedView)
            {
                var result = _newVersion.GetNewerVersion(viewName, context);
                if (result != null) return result;
            }
            return _fallbackViewLocator.LocateView(viewName, context);
        }

        public IEnumerable<ViewLocationResult> GetAllCurrentlyDiscoveredViews()
        {
            return _fallbackViewLocator.GetAllCurrentlyDiscoveredViews();
        }

    }
}
```

6. Tell nancy about the new ViewLocator

```
        protected override NancyInternalConfiguration InternalConfiguration
        {
            get
            {
                return NancyInternalConfiguration.WithOverrides
                (
                    nic =>
                    {
                        nic.ViewLocationProvider = typeof(ResourceViewLocationProvider);//use this or your equivalent
                        nic.ViewLocator = typeof(CachedViewLocator);
                    }
                );
            }            
        }
```

7. Then you can update it through a API like this:

```
public class YourModule : NancyModule
{
    public YourModule(INewViewLocationResultProvider provider)
    {
       Get["/yourupdateinterface"] = param =>
       {
          if(!provider.UseCachedView) return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;//in case you turn off the hot update
          //you can serialize your OneTimeUsedViewLocationResult with Newtonsoft.Json and store those views in any database, like mysql, redis, and load them here
          //data mock up
          TextReader tr = new StringReader(Resources.TextMain);                
          var vlr = new OneTimeUsedViewLocationResult("","index","cshtml",()=>tr);
          var dir = new Dictionary<string, ViewLocationResult> {{"index",vlr}};
          //mock up ends
          provider.UpdateCachedView(dir);
          return HttpStatusCode.OK;
       }
    }

}
```

Note: Those code above doesn't solve the manually map all the Location,Name,Extension for the ViewLocationResult thing menthions in my question, but since I endup build a view editor for my colleges to upload their views, I don't need to solve it anymore.